# Put "SET ROLE" or "SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION" behind a password

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I want an role to be able to use SET ROLE or SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION to switch to a more privileged role. However, this action should be behind an password. This password is not necessarily the actual password of the privileged user, but could be a different keyword.

For different reasons, connecting directly as the privileged role is not an option, and needs to be done in SQL.

My initial idea was to do this through a security definer (created as privileged Role) function which receives this "password", validates it internally, and then calls SET ROLE to the privileged role. However, SET ROLE and SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION do not work in security definer functions.

Is there a different avenue available or am I out of luck?

Comment: What you want _can_ be done, _if_ you can somehow, on the application level, forbid the `authenticator` role from doing anything else than calling your `login()` function. This is basically [what PostGREST does](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/auth.html); it connects to the DB using an `authenticator` `NOINHERIT` role. Then, if it was provided with a valid JWT token, it changes to that role, and otherwise to an `anon` role. As a DBA you are free to write your login function of choice to generate a valid JWT token, looking at whatever type of secret you elect to use.